# drawing highchart organization chart from MySQL data with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, highcharts

I want to dynamically create an organization chart from MySQL data
[As this link](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/organization-chart)   I have two files data.php and index.php
in the data.php I have read MySQL data and in index.php I have accessed the data from data.php file
following in data.php file

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "highcharts";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM org_chart";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$json = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. " " . $row["amount"]. "<br>";
    $json[]=[ (string)$row["parent"] , (string)$row["child"]];
}
echo json_encode($json);

} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
    $conn->close();
?>
```

following is above php file result

```
[["meraj","azim"],["meraj","masoma"],["meraj","jamal"],["mraj","zainab"],["azim","ajmal"], 
["azim","omid"]]
```

and following is my index file which is to show the org chart, but it is not showing
any help please

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sankey.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/organization.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<style>
    .highcharts-figure, .highcharts-data-table table {
        min-width: 360px;
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 1em auto;
    }

    .highcharts-data-table table {
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
        margin: 10px auto;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 500px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <figure class="highcharts-figure">
        <div id="container"></div>
   </figure>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            height: 600,
            inverted: true
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts Org Chart'
        },
        accessibility: {
            point: {
                descriptionFormatter: function (point) {
                    var nodeName = point.toNode.name,
                        nodeId = point.toNode.id,
                        nodeDesc = nodeName === nodeId ? nodeName : nodeName + ', ' + nodeId,
                        parentDesc = point.fromNode.id;
                    return point.index + '. ' + nodeDesc + ', reports to ' + parentDesc + '.';
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'organization',
            data: [],
        }],
    };
    $.getJSON("data.php" , function (data) {
        options.series[0].data = data;
        var chart = new Highcharts.chart('container', options);
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this what are you looking for ? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/09ex6dzu/). I think you are missing the "></script>" at "<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" "

Comment: Thank you sir now it working, but when the data getting more just showing lines not the chart itself. For one or two-parent node, it working well, any help regarding this

Comment: following is the captured chart image    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aNZN5A4Y5KyHR4gMOdYcJF2K3MNI4liD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That's an online reproduction of your code, it seems that everything works fine if your data output is an array which you shared: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2nsLhqb6/